# Passing an int array to a method

Tags: java

I am trying to **pass the values of an array to my second method** instead of using switch statements but I do not know what I am doing wrong. It keeps telling me that an identifier is expected but I didn't think I had to declare the variables again if I am passing them from one method to the other.

```
public static int infoObtainer()
{ 
    int g1, g2, ng1, ng2;
    String sgg, sgng, sngg, sngng;
    sgg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of years if you both plead guilty: ");
    g1=Integer.parseInt(sgg);
    sgng=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of years if you plead guilty and he pleads innocent: ");
    g2=Integer.parseInt(sgng);
    sngg=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of years if you plead innocent and he pleads guilty: ");
    ng1=Integer.parseInt(sngg); 
    sngng=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter numner of years if you both plead innocent: ");
    ng2=Integer.parseInt(sngng);

    int[] jailtime = {g1,g2,ng1,ng2}; 

    return jailtime;
}

public static void decisionMaker(jailtime[])
{
    if (g1<=ng1)
    {
        if (g2<=ng2)
        {
            if (g1<=g2)
            {
                Sytem.out.println(" Plead Guilty");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Plead Gulity");
            }
        }
        else
            if (g1<=ng2)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't help");
            }
    }
    else
    {
        if (g2<=ng2)
        {
            if (ng1<=g2)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't help");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Plead Guilty");
            }
        }
        else
            if (ng1<=ng2)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't help");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Plead Guilty");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a method signature, the parameters have a type and a name, replace `(jailtime[])` with `(int[] jailtime)` for instance

Comment: You have to specify what `jailtime` is here `public static void decisionMaker( jailtime[])`. Change to `public static void decisionMaker(int[] jailtime)`

Answer (score 3):

Java arrays like their non-array counterparts need a type definition.

change

```
public static void decisionMaker( jailtime[])
```

to

```
public static void decisionMaker(int[] jailtime)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check how a function should be defined in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

And check your method's signature again.
You should read some basics tutorials, it is fast and useful

```
public static void myFunction (Object myObj) {}
```

Or in your specific case

```
public static void decisionMaker (int[] jailtime) { ... }
```

And NB that the modified values of the passed array in the method will also change for your array in `main`.